# Should I go for better processor or better GPU for graphics rendering?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, rendering

I need a new laptop. I am not considering building a desktop. I work with 3D modeling of furniture/ambients and rendering software such as sketchup/vray and I need mobility.

Should I invest in a notebook that offers **older processor and the latest GPU** or the opposite **latest processor with an older GPU** ?

Lets assume I dont care about HDD and both options have at least 8GB RAM for the Operating System.

(i.e.: i7-6700HQ + GTX1080 ***or***    i7-8750H + GTX 1050)

Comment: Depends on the [benchmarks](https://www.userbenchmark.com/). In the specific example above, the 1080 equipped computer will outperform the other computer in most 3D scenarios. If you were to tell us the exact computers you are comparing, or better yet, **specify your needs and budget** (e.g. 16 Gb RAM, Preferably RTX 1080, under $1.5K ) we can find the best computer for your user case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, I'd recommend having a GPU of the same calibre and age as your CPU. And given your needs, this may well suit you.

I'm not an expert in all this graphical stuff, but AFAIK most modellers (inc SketchUp) tend to need to do linear calculations and thus are usually restricted to a single core, so the speed of an individual core is key - so get a good CPU.

Whereas renderers like VRay usually use CUDA on the GPU, so perhaps you should prioritise your GPU? VRay and some other renderers can supplement/help their GPU using the CPU, so spare CPU cores may be useful.

So in short, get the best CPU & GPU there is!

A bit impractical if you are budget-limited? Of course, so have 3 options:

1. Prioritise Modelling (CPU)
2. Prioritise Rendering (GPU)
3. Or hedge your bets with a balanced config - comparable CPU & GPU.

So which do you do most of?

Back to your sample configs, it is worth noting that the performance gap between the i7 6700HQ and the 8750H is approx 40% (based on user benchmarks). The gap between the 1050 and the 180 however is about 250%. If you want to adopt my balanced recommendation, you'd pair the 6700HQ with a GTX1060 or better.

Comment: Thank you! Looking for a _balanced_ performance gap percentage was key to my decision! Thanks.